# How to manipulate a variable multiple times in a single command in CMD?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

Everyone.
I was wondering if it was possible to manipulate a variable multiple times in a single command?

For example, I want to SUBSTRING and REPLACE TEXT as the following commands:

```
:: Print the first 8 characters:
echo %TIME:~0:8%

:: Replace white spaces with zeros
echo %TIME: =0%
```

Desired output (Print Time without the milliseconds AND replace the whitespace on the left side with a 0)

```
09:15:23
```

So, is there away I could combine both variable manipulations into one single command?

I want to avoid storing the time in an additional variable and just print it out the way I desire (as mentioned above).

Comment: No. Offset and Replacement substitutions cannot be combined into a single command.

Comment: @T3RR0R Would it be possible if we use pipe ?

Comment: Your question was can it be done in single command, the answer is no. It can be don as multiple commands on the same line, but that was not what you were asking.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what exactly you mean... Your first example does **not** get a SUBSTRING, it `echo` (output) a result in the screen. The same thing in your second example. The command to get a substring or replace text is `SET`. I think you are confusing a _command_ with a _variable manipulation_, and a variable manipulation manages _one variable_ only. Please, put an example of what you want to get as result...

Comment: @Aacini Ok. I will try.

Comment: @T3RR0R I just want to do both commands without storing the time in a variable that I have to create. I don't mind multiple commands or pipes as long as I don't initialized a variable.

Comment: @Aacini Maybe programming terminologies aren't my thing. I may not have phrased myself clearly. I thought %TIME% was indeed an environment variable in Windows. Anyways, I just wanna achieve the result of the commands I mentioned above without the need of initializing an additional variable as a workaround.

Comment: @CodingNoob that is exactly the purpose of variables. If all you want to do is output the time in that format with your arbitrary requirement of not setting or modifying variables, use a powershell command: `powershell -c get-date -format hh:mm:ss`

Comment: @T3RR0R Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately, I can't use powershell. I'm stuck with CMD for reasons.

Comment: OK. This is cheating. This achieves what you want without initializing an _additional_ variable: `set "TIME=%TIME: =0%" & echo !TIME:~0,8! & set "TIME="` It requires EnableDelayedExpansion...

Comment: @Aacini At least your command kinda resolved my issue. Please post it as answer (with EnableDelayedExpansion) so that I could accept it as the answer. Thank you very much for your cooperation.

Comment: Done. See [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75431767/778560)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each variable manipulation manipulates *one variable*, so your result requires *two commands*. You can, however, place the two commands in a single line and re-use *the same variable* in order to not initialize an *additional* variable. That is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "TIME=%TIME: =0%" & echo !TIME:~0,8! & set "TIME="
```

Answer (score 1):

not possible in a single command, but possible in one line without setting another environment variable:

```
for /f "delims=.," %%a in ("%time: =0%") do echo %%a
```

You already know how to replace spaces with zeros. The `for` loop dissects the result, effectively removing the centiseconds. `"Delims=.,"` takes care of the delimiter (`,` in some languages, `.` in others)

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I tested your command but it didn't work for me. I tested it directly in CMD window. Are there other things that I need to do?

Comment: For use directly on command line, replace every `%%a` with `%a`. If it still fails, tell me the exact output you get.